# Python Beautiful soup not working how to scrape div with class='st' in google search this is my code

Tags: python-3.x

The `results` value is always empty. How can I get the results inside the div with class `st`?

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests

  response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=tom and jerry")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
  results = soup.find_all('div', class_='st')
  for text in headline_results:
    print(text)
```

Comment: Typo in for loop. You are looping over header_results instead of results

Comment: From the html, I can't find any class with "st". Can you show which part of the html you are planning to scrap?. The closest I can find is `class="sc"`

Comment: class st inside a class s inside class rc inside class g inside class srg in google search html page

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reviewing the response.text to make sure that there are, indeed, div's with the class?

Try `print(response.text)` or output to file and review.

Comment: odd... saved `response.text` to a file and the only instances of `st` as a whole word are in the IDs `st-toggle` and `st-card`

Comment: I wasn't able to get any st-* classes on my test run. Any luck with abhilb's suggestion that you have a typo?